# It is a riddle of today?

Tags: riddle, steganography

Today is a very significant day.
Here, people died. And yet, many were saved.
Emergency call is the same as today.
Death and destruction is the hallmark of this day.
A number is what it is. Catastrophic number it turned out to be.
Ten is the mean for this number(s).
Exact 16 years  to this day, is what I am talking about.

Comment: The commemoration is a nice thought, but isn't this rather too straightforward to be called a riddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today is a very significant day.

> Today is 9/11

Here, people died. And yet, many were saved.

> around 3k casualties, with 343 firefighters and 71 law enforcement officers (my figures were off at first, sorry- corrected)

Emergency call is the same as today.

> 911

Death and destruction is the hallmark of this day.
A number is what it is. Catastrophic number it turned out to be.

> again,3k deaths

Ten is the mean for this number(s).

> 9 and 11, the mean is 10

Exact 16 years to this day, is what I am talking about.

> 9-11-01

Comment: Read the first letter of each line.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> the date of the 9/11 attacks on the twin towers in NYC.

Why:

> It is both the first letters of each line and an otherwise general description of the day, including referencing the years since.